# prove that the sequence given by recurrence converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a:
 $a_0>0$, and $a_{n+1}=\sin(a_n)$. 
I need to prove that the sequence $a_{n=0}^\infty$ converges, then calculate the limit.

I have proved that is crescent, then I got stuck.

Comment: This is likely a problem that has been solved here previously.  I'll see if I can find a duplicate for you.  When you say "I have proved that is *crescent*", I suspect what you mean is *contractive" (with respect to the function $\sin x$ that is repeatedly applied).  Can you clarify what exactly you did prove?

Comment: ...also duplicate of [How find this limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\underbrace{\sin{\sin{\cdots\sin{x}}}}_{n},x\in R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736725/how-find-this-limit-lim-n-to-infty-underbrace-sin-sin-cdots-sinx-n), [Limit of infinite loops of sin x as n tends to infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732030/limit-of-infinite-loops-of-sin-x-as-n-tends-to-infinity).